# Osmosis and halocline

Tags: osmosis

Osmosis can release a lot of power - 2.5 kJ per litre. This is equivalent to 250 m fall or rising temperature of the water more than half of degree.

But mixing of salted and fresh water is surprisingly(at least for me) slow. We can even create a pet halocline in a glass and judging by how stable it is, mixing of water is very slow - much less than 1 mm per second.

Why it is so? Should not release of all that energy help mixing at least in some situations?

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 3):

Osmotic pressures can be startingly high. For example seawater has an osmotic pressure of around 28 atmospheres so if you could use this pressure to do work then a lot of work could be extracted.

The problem is that to make the semipermeable membrane move requires water molecules to diffuse from the pure water side to the seawater side and diffusion in water is very slow. It's slow because the mean free path of a water molecule in liquid water is effectively zero due to collisions with other water molecules. As you've observed in your glass of water/saline the interface takes days to move even a few millimetres. Sadly, as far as I know there is no way round this.